# Debatching Biztalk flat file message into individual grouped flat files based on value

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

Have an issue where I am trying to debatch a flat file in BizTalk Server (comma delimited to tab-delimited) into individual flat files based on a value (in this example it would be PONumber) in the original file.

Sample input:

```
PartNumber,Weight,PONumber,Other
21519,234,46788,1
81919,456,47115,1
91910,789,47115,1
```

This would outcome into 2 messages such as:

```
PartNumber  Weight  PONumber    Other
21519   234 46788   1
```

and

```
PartNumber  Weight  PONumber    Other
81919   456 47115   1
91910   789 47115   1
```

I have seen similar things but no definite answers, or samples are dead links. Does anyone have a sample where they have done something like this or have a good solution?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense, both are PONumber = 1.  Did you mean the second message to be PONumber =2?  If so, what you are looking at is a scatter gather pattern

Comment: @Dijkgraaf If you look above its tab delimited, the PONumber values are the 46788, and 47117 values. Sorry if that was unclear from original description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:  Convoy pattern**

Change your schema so that it has a max occurs of 1 for the PO line, this will debatch each line into it's own messages when it is received.

Promote the PONumber so that it is a promoted property in the message context.

Have an Orchestration that has a correlation set based on the PO number, and initialises this on the first receive shape.

Have a receive shape with a following correlation that is in a wait shape inside a loop to receive all the other lines with the same PO number and combine them into a single message.

**Option 2: Staging database**

The other option is to just insert all of the rows into a SQL database, and then have a stored procedure that you poll that gets all the lines for a single PO.

This can sometimes be simpler, and avoids the issue of [Zombies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/working-with-convoy-scenarios#zombies) as you can implement this as a messaging only pattern or using a simpler Orcherstration without a loop.

Comment: Never done all these steps with an orchestration (non-savvy with them), do you have an example link to anything like this? I will try to follow in the meantime!

Comment: @JackBlack I've had a look around, and there are some articles on Correlation, and some on Convoy patterns that come close, but not exactly that matches that.   I've also given you another option.

Comment: Will see if I can find some example of number 2... sounds like a good option but again unsure how to set this up.